# Cutom error page in laravel 5.1 modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.1. Created a admin modules in this structure for backend.To custom HTTP Error Pages, created /modules/Admin/Resources/views/errors/404.blade.php this page. But its not accessing, for 404 status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at how HTTP Exceptions are rendered in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler@render`.

Then implement your own rendering inside `\App\Exception\Handler@render`

Comment: Yes, i reviewed code from  \Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler@render added in my file -`modules/Admin/Exceptions/Handler.php`.
Code :- `public function render($request, Exception $e)
 {
  if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
  {
   abort(404);
  }
  return parent::render($request, $e);
 }`
but still not works.

Comment: exit & dies statements are also not printing in above code.

Comment: Did you call your modules/Admin/Exceptions/Handler inside app\Exception\Handler? If not I don't know how you'd expect that Laravel will do it for you.

Comment: Yes, i used `namespace Modules\Admin\Exceptions;` in file `modules/Admin/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Comment: I'm not talking about your namespace, where do you call the render method of your implementation of the Exception handler?

Comment: thanks @PeterPan666. I called render method in `/bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: Lol ok I don't know your structure but I think it should be inside `\App\Exception\Handler@render`... But anyway, I'm glad that I helped you ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102694/discussion-between-sharad-b-and-peterpan666).